# How to use a Skin file (.asz) file in resource file in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I am currently using `Alpha lite` demo to give various looks to my delphi 7 application. I am in doubt about how to include their Skin file (.asz extension) so that I can port my Delphi application without losing the Look. I am aware that i will have to include it in a .RES file. How to do that ?
I have made  a small function to load the resource :

```
Function LoadResourceFromFile() : Boolean;
Var
  hFind , hRes : THandle;
Begin
  hFind := FindResource(HInstance,'SkinsVista',RT_RCDATA);
  If hFind <> 0 Then
  Begin
    hRes := LoadResource(HInstance,hFind);
    If hRes <> 0 Then
    Begin
      // what to do now ?
    End;
  End;
End;
```

Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the following code. It's untested by me, but based on [`this post`](http://www.alphaskins.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=3122) from vendor support so I hope it should be the right way to do so:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
const
  SkinName = 'MySkin';
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'SkinsVista', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    sSkinManager1.InternalSkins.Add;
    sSkinManager1.InternalSkins[sSkinManager1.InternalSkins.Count - 1].Name := SkinName;
    sSkinManager1.InternalSkins[sSkinManager1.InternalSkins.Count - 1].PackedData.LoadFromStream(ResStream);
    sSkinManager1.SkinName := SkinName;
    sSkinManager1.Active := True;
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I have only the same free version of the `AlphaControls` as you have and there's no source code nor documentation; this answer is based on [`this post`](http://www.alphaskins.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=3122) from vendor. The only thing I've added here is loading from resource to stream so I'm afraid I can't elaborate this more :-( Maybe you can try to ask vendor, but hard to say if they provide you such details when you are only free user, but maybe yes.